# Cannot delimit a record using \n as some values in the field has \n chars

Tags: python

I am trying to read a file in python which has some records like this:

```
This|is|a|si
ngle|reco
rd|
```

The entire text is a single record but the values 'single' and 'record' have \n in it because of which my record delimiter (which is set to \n) is messing up records like this.

My field delimiter is |, and I want these records to be read like as shown below.

```
This|is|a|single|record|
```

I have tried the below:
with open(infile, 'Ur') as origin:
        for line in origin:
            tempDest.write(line.strip('\n'))

The problem with this is, it messes up the lines above and below the record we are trying to fix.
For example:

OK|RECORD|
This|is|a|si
ngle|reco
rd|
OK|RECORD2|

looks like this:
OK|RECORD|This|is|a|single|record|OK|RECORD2|

[image]

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If the entire file is a single record you just need to read it completely and split it at `|`:</strike>

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read().split('|'))
```

Comment: Yes, but eventually the file has to look like this:OK|RECORD|\nThis|is|a|single|record|\nOK|RECORD2|

Comment: How are you supposed to recognize different records? If newlines are both used as record separators and inside records without escape? Do they always start with OK? Is OK not allowed to appear anywhere else?

Comment: And that is my dilemma too. No, the example I shared is just a sample.I dont have a concrete character after which I can add the \n after the records are fixed. It seems like the field values were entered manually in a DB with \n in some field values. I wanted to see if I can fix such records and files before I contact the people to fix that in import file they gave me. Moreover, I was trying to see if only the affected records which have \n in field values can be isolated, fixed and added back into a new file.

Comment: @Rg If the number of elements per row is fixed there's a simple solution, if that's not known either them this is simply unsolvable.

Comment: @Voo: Right, the number of elements per row is 70(Thats what I got from the header). So you mean, add the \n after every 70th element??

Comment: @Rg Pretty much, although technically you only have to remove newlines not add any.